# panas groupby and checking against prior/next row

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, row

I am allocating certain data into year and sometimes it falls on wrong year due to timing and need to manually correct data.  (long story)  See example below and it will be easier to understand:

```
import pandas as pd

years=[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005]
symbols=['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC', 'DEF','DEF','DEF', 'DEF','DEF','DEF']
c=[3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3]
df= pd.DataFrame({'y':years, 'g':symbols, 'count':c})

           y    g  count
    0   2000  ABC      3
    1   2001  ABC      3
    2   2002  ABC      2
    3   2003  ABC      4
    4   2004  ABC      3
    5   2005  ABC      3
    6   2000  DEF      3
    7   2001  DEF      3
    8   2002  DEF      4
    9   2003  DEF      2
    10  2004  DEF      3
    11  2005  DEF      3
```

I'd like my output to look like this
(It means I'd like to move first of 2003 ABC observation into 2002, and last of 2002 DEF observation into 2003)

```
           y    g  count result
0   2000  ABC      3
1   2001  ABC      3
2   2002  ABC      2
3   2003  ABC      4   2002
4   2004  ABC      3
5   2005  ABC      3
6   2000  DEF      3
7   2001  DEF      3
8   2002  DEF      4   2003
9   2003  DEF      2
10  2004  DEF      3
11  2005  DEF      3
```

I wasn't sure how to write code to compare each row to prior and next row while grouping by.....

Comment: The pattern is not clear...

Comment: if previous_row.C < current_row.C  and next_row.C> current_row.C then do something...

Comment: not cleat yet....

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do what I want to do by groupby().shift()

```
df['prev']=df.groupby(['g'])['count'].shift(1)
 df['next']=df.groupby(['g'])['count'].shift(-1)
```